# Cannot resolve symbol R and xml errors when i compile to V4.4.2 android studio

Tags: android

Is there any way to create a project without Material design in Android studio?

I have create a new project with wizard on V23 but I need compile on `4.4.2` so i go to settings/properties and I changed Compile SDK Version to API `19 Android KitKat`.
But when its compile android show me **cannot resolve symbol R** in activity and the following erros.

i try clean up, recompiles restart android  and nothing works, if i compile againt to V23 its works...

**Errors in XML:**

> C:\Users\Pagan\AndroidStudioProjects\PrimaRiesgo\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-ldltr-v21\values-ldltr-v21.xml
>   Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
>   C:\Users\Pagan\AndroidStudioProjects\PrimaRiesgo\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v21\values-v21.xml
>   Error:(13) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Inverse'.
>   Error:(15) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large.Inverse'. Error:(21) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium.Inverse'. Error:(28)
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small.Inverse'.
>   Error:(201) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar'.
>   Error:(203) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.ProgressBar.Horizontal'. Error:(211) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:Theme.Material'. Error:(221) Error retrieving parent for
>   item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Theme.Material.Light'. Error:(163) Error retrieving parent
>   for item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.AutoCompleteTextView'. Error:(174) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:Widget.Material.EditText'. Error:(6) Error retrieving
>   parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'. Error:(3) Error retrieving
>   parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material'. Error:(4) Error retrieving parent
>   for item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body1'. Error:(5) Error retrieving
>   parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Body2'. Error:(7) Error retrieving
>   parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Caption'. Error:(8) Error retrieving
>   parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display1'. Error:(9) Error retrieving
>   parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display2'. Error:(10) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display3'. Error:(11) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Display4'. Error:(12) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Headline'. Error:(14) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Large'. Error:(16) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
>   Error:(18) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'. Error:(20)
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Medium'. Error:(22) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Menu'. Error:(23) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Subtitle'.
>   Error:(25) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.SearchResult.Title'. Error:(27) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Small'. Error:(29) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Subhead'. Error:(30) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Title'. Error:(31) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
>   Error:(33) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle.Inverse'.
>   Error:(35) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'. Error:(37)
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title.Inverse'.
>   Error:(39) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Subtitle'.
>   Error:(41) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionMode.Title'. Error:(43)
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button'. Error:(44)
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Large'.
>   Error:(46) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.PopupMenu.Small'. Error:(48)
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Button'. Error:(49) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.TextView.SpinnerItem'.
>   Error:(50) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Subtitle'.
>   Error:(52) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Title'. Error:(152)
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabText'. Error:(154)
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionBar.TabView'. Error:(156)
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton'. Error:(158) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.CloseMode'. Error:(161)
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:Widget.Material.ActionButton.Overflow'.
>   Error:(166) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button'. Error:(167)
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless'. Error:(168)
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Borderless.Colored'.
>   Error:(169) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Small'.
>   Error:(170) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.ButtonBar'.
>   Error:(171) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.CheckBox'. Error:(172) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:Widget.Material.CompoundButton.RadioButton'. Error:(173)
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:Widget.Material.DropDownItem.Spinner'. Error:(177)
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:Widget.Material.ImageButton'. Error:(178) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'. Error:(180)
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabText'.
>   Error:(182) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.Light.ActionBar.TabView'. Error:(184) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:Widget.Material.Light.PopupMenu'. Error:(190) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:Widget.Material.ListPopupWindow'. Error:(192) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:Widget.Material.ListView'. Error:(193) Error retrieving
>   parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.ListView.DropDown'. Error:(195) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:Widget.Material.PopupMenu'. Error:(205) Error retrieving
>   parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar'. Error:(206) Error retrieving
>   parent for item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.SeekBar'. Error:(207) Error retrieving parent
>   for item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.Spinner'. Error:(208) Error retrieving parent
>   for item: No resource found that matches the given name
>   'android:Widget.Material.TextView.SpinnerItem'. Error:(209) Error
>   retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the given
>   name 'android:Widget.Material.Toolbar.Button.Navigation'.
>   C:\Users\Pagan\AndroidStudioProjects\PrimaRiesgo\app\build\intermediates\exploded-aar\com.android.support\appcompat-v7\23.4.0\res\values-v21\values-v21.xml
>   Error:(58, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:colorAccent'. Error:(58, 5) No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'. Error:(58, 5) No
>   resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:colorControlActivated'. Error:(58, 5) No resource found that
>   matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
>   Error:(58, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:colorControlNormal'. Error:(58, 5) No resource found that
>   matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'. Error:(58, 5) No
>   resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:colorPrimaryDark'. Error:(102, 5) No resource found that
>   matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'. Error:(105, 5)
>   No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:colorAccent'. Error:(105, 5) No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'. Error:(105, 5) No
>   resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:colorControlActivated'. Error:(105, 5) No resource found that
>   matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
>   Error:(105, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:colorControlNormal'. Error:(105, 5) No resource found that
>   matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'. Error:(105, 5) No
>   resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:colorPrimaryDark'. Error:(149, 5) No resource found that
>   matches the given name: attr 'android:windowElevation'. Error:(186, 5)
>   No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:overlapAnchor'. Error:(197, 5) No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr 'android:overlapAnchor'. Error:(231, 5) No
>   resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:colorAccent'. Error:(231, 5) No resource found that matches
>   the given name: attr 'android:colorButtonNormal'. Error:(231, 5) No
>   resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:colorControlActivated'. Error:(231, 5) No resource found that
>   matches the given name: attr 'android:colorControlHighlight'.
>   Error:(231, 5) No resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:colorControlNormal'. Error:(231, 5) No resource found that
>   matches the given name: attr 'android:colorPrimary'. Error:(231, 5) No
>   resource found that matches the given name: attr
>   'android:colorPrimaryDark'.
>   C:\Users\Pagan\AndroidStudioProjects\PrimaRiesgo\app\build\intermediates\res\merged\debug\values-v23\values-v23.xml
>   Error:(36) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Spinner.Underlined'.
>   Error:(3) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name
>   'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.ActionBar.Menu'. Error:(4)
>   Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that matches the
>   given name 'android:TextAppearance.Material.Widget.Button.Inverse'.
>   Error:(33) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.Button.Colored'.
>   Error:(34) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar.Indicator'.
>   Error:(35) Error retrieving parent for item: No resource found that
>   matches the given name 'android:Widget.Material.RatingBar.Small'.
>   Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.

> com.android.ide.common.process.ProcessException: org.gradle.process.internal.ExecException: Process 'command
>   'C:\Users\Pagan\AppData\Local\Android\Sdk\build-tools\23.0.3\aapt.exe''
>   finished with non-zero exit value 1

Answer (score 0):

Check your res-folder. Some object there might not work on api 19 but be known in api 23. Also you can check the appcompat-classes.

There was no material before android 5.x so you might need to archieve backward-compatibilitiy.

Comment: Thanks for answer. Are there any way to change theme materials to another theme for my project?

Comment: You can define seperate res-files for each api-versions by using qualifier similar to f.e. the languages -> /res/folder-v21/resfile.xml  <- this res shall be used from api 21 upwards until another folder for a higher version with a identic named file (/res/folder-v24/resfile.xml) is definied. This works for any res, no matter if style, layout, mipmap or anything else.